# Problems with Python Version on R with Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, r

I would like to run `keras` and `tensorflow` on R for deep learning purposes,
however when I perform `install.keras()` I get this error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow Erreur
>   : Error 1 occurred installing TensorFlow

Seems that Tensorflow needs Python 3 installed. I work on Mac so Python 2 is installed by default. I have downloaded Python 3, but Python 2 is still the default for R, so I still get this message. Does anyone know what i can do?
I was told not to remove Python 2 as it may compromise some applications.

Comment: Try running `pip install --upgrade virtualenv` and `pip install tensorflow -U` in terminal to make sure everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

> I have downloaded python 3 but python2 is still the default for R.

This sounds like you just need to adjust the path to prefer your Python 3 install.  In your home directory you should have a file called `.bash_profile` where your path can be set. Change it to point to your Python 3 install location. For example, mine looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

This means that an executable in `/usr/local/bin` will be preferred over one in the system path (which is represented by `$PATH`.) You'll need to log out and back in for this change to take effect.

> I was told not to remove python 2 as it may compromise some applications

That's absolutely true. Don't ever replace system-provided tools on any OS!

Comment: Thanks, I still have an issue as i don't manage to find the executable for python 3  (Username$ /Applications/Python\ 3.6). I have set the path to the python 3.6 folder but it still does not work...